# How to make appsettings.json is configured in project instead of bin folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this test class code in .NET Core 3.1 which only works when I place the appsettings.test.json in the project bin folder. How do I make it configurable at the project folder instead?

```
public class ServiceTest
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

    public IngestServiceTest_GetNextFileToIngest()
    {
        // Note: appsettings is configured at the bin folder at the moment.
        _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json").Build();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think it is good idea. If you put the appsettings file there it will be exposed to the public after you publish. Which is very bad in terms of security.

Comment: the application looks for the file in the same folder from where the application is running. Application runs from `bin` folder that's why it works when you have file in the bin folder. If you have file in the project folder,  you need to set the `Copy To Output Directory` property of that file to `Copy If Newer`. so that whenever you build the project, the file will be copied to the `bin` folder. and code will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

right click on your appsettings file, click properties, and in `Copy to Output Directory` select `Copy if newer`.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ZBg.png)

Comment: Can put the screen shot? When I right click appsettings, the property window is empty.